# Assign string to object based on filename with multiple conditions

Tags: r, assign

I'm using some switches in my R script based on the provided data and I would like to automatize the recognition of said data. The files I'm using contain the required information in their name, I'm looking for a good way to match and assign this parts.

file names:

```sh
# Folder1:
T090_V4_plate1_S90_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
T090_V4_plate1_S90_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
# Folder2:
T091_V4_plate2_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz 
T091_V4_plate2_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz 
# Folder3:
TNT_2017_13_V34_plate4_S13_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
TNT_2017_13_V34_plate4_S13_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
TNT_2017_14_V34_plate4_S14_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
TNT_2017_14_V34_plate4_S14_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

the two values I would like to assign to objects are `V3` or `V34` to the object `primerset` and `plate[1-4]` to `plate`. I tried it like this:

```r
if (length(list.files(pattern = "plate1")) > 1) {
plate <<- "plate1"
} else if (length(list.files(pattern = "plate2")) > 1) {
plate <<- "plate2"
} else if (length(list.files(pattern = "plate3")) > 1) {
plate <<- "plate3"
} else if (length(list.files(pattern = "plate4")) > 1) {
plate <<- "plate4"}

if (length(list.files(pattern = "V4")) > 1) {
primerset <<- "V4"
} else if (length(list.files(pattern = "V34")) > 1) {
primerset <<- "V34"
}

# print message based on detected values from file names
if (primerset == "V34"){
  cat("sequence length is 301 bp")
} else if (primerset == "V4"){
  cat("sequence length is 250 bp")
}
```

It works fine, but it looks complicated and easy to fail. Is there a more elegant solution? I would prefer not to load a package just for this task.

Additionally I don't know how to add a break if more than one condition is met, e.g. `plate1` and `plate2` in the same folder (I have the data sets separated, but just to be on the safe side).

**Solution:**

Based on the answers below these two versions also test if only one instance of `primerset` or `plate` is present:

```r
filenames <- list.files()
if (length(unique(sub(".*_(plate\\d)_.*", "\\1", filenames))) == 1) {
  plate <- unique(sub(".*_(plate\\d)_.*", "\\1", filenames))
}
```

```r
matches = stringr::str_match(filenames, '_(V\\d+)_(plate\\d)')
if (length(unique(matches[, 2])) == 1) {
  primerset = unique(matches[, 2])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, we can use `sub` to extract specific part of the string.

```
primerset <- sub(".*_(V4|V34)_.*", "\\1", x)
#Or more generally
#primerset <- sub(".*_(V\\d+)_.*", "\\1", x)
plate <- sub(".*_(plate\\d)_.*", "\\1", x)
```

where `x` is vector of all the filenames

```
x <- c("T090_V4_plate1_S90_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz",
       "T090_V4_plate1_S90_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz",
       "T091_V4_plate2_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz",
       "T091_V4_plate2_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz",
       "TNT_2017_13_V34_plate4_S13_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz",
       "TNT_2017_13_V34_plate4_S13_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz",
       "TNT_2017_14_V34_plate4_S14_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz",
       "TNT_2017_14_V34_plate4_S14_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz")
```

Comment: I modified it to: `filenames <- list.files(rawPath)
if (length(unique(sub(".*_(plate\\d)_.*", "\\1", filenames))) == 1) {
  plate <- unique(sub(".*_(plate\\d)_.*", "\\1", filenames))
} `

Answer (score 1):

This calls for a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). Using the {stringr} package, you would write:

```
matches = stringr::str_match(x, '_(V\\d+)_(plate\\d)')
primerset = matches[, 2]
plate = matches[, 3]
```

That is: match an underscore, followed by `'V'` and a single digit, followed by underscore, followed by `'plate'` and a single digit. You can extend the expression to also match the lane, mate and replicate.

Best of all, the above is vectorised so it works correctly with a vector of filenames.

Note that, either way, you should *not* be using `<<-` here (this performs global rather than local assignment and is very rarely appropriate).

Comment: I modified it to `_(V\\d+)_(plate\\d)` as it gave `NA` for `V34` and added a unique() for a test. Thank you for the hint on `<<-`, I thought it was required in this case, as the objects were assigned within a function